# Does onboarding include sign up?

Tags: security, authentication, onboarding, verification

I'm designing a matchmaking platform for influencers and marketers. I want to create a secure platform that verifies identities (both influencers, and marketers that work for legit brands).

I am struggling on a couple things:

Do I include a sign up flow? IF so, how do I ask for information? I was thinking of the experience more like signing up to request a demo (this is popular for this type of platforms). And then the person has to verify their information through a 1:1 meeting - which leaves me confused how to design the **user flow** for this scenario.

Or do I sign the user up quickly, and they access the platform (but can't interact with any influencers for example as a marketer) - until they verify their information (which could take a couple days).

Answer (score 2):

"I strongly believe in the second:

The process of verifying identity can be quite complex and should be accompanied by a dedicated tutorial. It would be very difficult, if not impossible, to implement such a tutorial within the registration process. Take, for example, platforms like Binance and eToro where the basic registration process are simple info request, and you then proceed to your personal area to complete the necessary steps for identity verification. Moreover, these platforms provide a dedicated tutorial to guide users through the verification process.

By following the registration process and reaching your personal area, things become more organized. The sign up process usually designed as a wizard, while the verification process, in my opinion, should be presented as a "star" menu. This allows users to easily exit and return to the verification process without having to start the entire registration process anew."

Answer (score 1):

Your second option seem good and avoid identity issue and trust problem with your platform

1. **I suggest you don't lock interaction, let users interact and navigate but let them know all their actions are in "stand by" and waiting for verification.**

---

2. Some social media have a **verification badge**, you should investigate creating a sign-up form with authentification like twitter, facebook, google, and if an account is verified you don't have to worry about your verification process... (**check API if you can collect this type of data**)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are another Facebook, Twitter, Instagram or any other renowned brand, I feel sign up just ends up creating fake account and higher customer churn.

I think you should strive to provide value to your users first. Make them do some task and then probably ask them to create profile. Doing this you have made them invest their time and effort and if they are already seeing the value, all the admin stuffs become secondary and they will be happy to oblige.